# XPATH some divs not reachable

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

**Intro**

I have to add to my crawler "Others also bought"-items of certain productlink.
Its really weird for me, because there are divs like"open-on-mobile" and "inner generated", what does this mean for me?

**Goal**

I already got every important information which are needed, except of the "others also bought", after trying of hours, i decided to ask here, before i waste more time and get more frustrated

**HTML construction**

[image: click me]

**My code**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from ..items import DuifcsvItem
import csv

class DuifSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "duif"
    allowed_domains = ['duif.nl']
    custom_settings = {'FIELD_EXPORT_FIELDS' : ['SKU', 'Title', 'Title_small', 'NL_PL_PC', 'Description']}
    with open("duifonlylinks.csv","r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        start_urls = [items['Link'] for items in reader]
    
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse'),
    )



    def parse(self, response):
        card = response.xpath('//div[@class="heading"]')

        if not card:
            print('No productlink', response.url)        
        
        items = DuifcsvItem()
        items['Link'] = response.url
        items['SKU'] = response.xpath('//p[@class="desc"]/text()').get().strip()
        items['Title'] = response.xpath('//h1[@class="product-title"]/text()').get()
        items['Title_small'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="left"]/p/text()').get()
        items['NL_PL_PC'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="desc"]/ul/li/em/text()').getall()
        items['Description'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="item"]/p/text()').getall()
        yield items
```

**Actual Webpage**: https://www.duif.nl/product/pot-seal-matt-finish-light-pink-large

Perfect would be, if could access this href with xpath

**XPATH i already tried**

```
>>> response.xpath('//div[@class="title"]/h3/text()').get()
>>> response.xpath('//div[@class="inner generated"]/div//h3/text()').get()
>>> response.xpath('//div[@class="wrap-products"]/div/div/a/@href').get()
>>> response.xpath('/div[@class="description"]/div/h3/text()').get()
>>> response.xpath('//div[@class="open-on-mobile"]/div/div/div/a/@href').get()
>>> response.xpath('//div[@class="product cross-square white"]/a/@href').get()
>>> response.xpath('//a[@class="product-link"]').get()
>>> response.xpath('//a[@class="product-link"]').getall()
```

Comment: Have you checked the actual sources? (not the DOM) https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#caveats-with-inspecting-the-live-browser-dom

Comment: Your HTML elements are obviously loaded by AJAX. Since scrapy only donwload base HTML code, your `other products` cannot appear in your scrapy response. You have 2 ways to achieve your goal: scrapy-splash or tools to control browsers, e.g: Selenium, Puppeteer.

Comment: Or https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find "Others also bought" product ids in this part of HTML (see `createCrossSellItems` section):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
            createUpsellItems("885034747 | 885034800 | 885034900 |")
                        createCrossSellItems("885034347 | 480010600 | 480010700 | 010046700 | 500061967 | 480011000 |")
    })
</script>
```

But adding details for all these products to your main item is a bit tricky. First you need to understand how do you want to save this information (one-to-many). It may be a single field `OtherAlsoBought` where you'll save a JSON-like structure for example. Or you can use many fields like `OtherAlsoBought_Product_1_Title`, `OtherAlsoBought_Product_1_Link`, `OtherAlsoBought_Product_2_Title`, `OtherAlsoBought_Product_2_Link` etc.

One possible way to collect these details will be to save all product ids into an array and next `yield` one id at a time (simple `GET` `https://www.duif.nl/api/v2/catalog/product?itemcode=885034347_Parent` should work but with a correct `Referer` header) but also passing products array (using `meta` or `cb_kwargs`) to get next id. Of course you also need to pass your main `item` for each request (to add current product details to it and `yield` everything at the end).

**UPDATE**
You need to add fields you need to the below code:

```
import scrapy
import json
import re

class DuifSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name="duif"
    start_urls = ['https://www.duif.nl/product/pot-seal-matt-finish-light-pink-large']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = {}
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//h1[@class="product-title"]/text()').get()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['cross_sell'] = []

        cross_sell_items_raw = response.xpath('//script[contains(., "createCrossSellItems(")]/text()').re_first(r'createCrossSellItems\("([^"]+)')
        cross_sell_items = re.findall(r"\d+", cross_sell_items_raw)

        if cross_sell_items:
            cross_sell_item_id = cross_sell_items.pop(0)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                f"https://www.duif.nl/api/v2/catalog/product?itemcode={cross_sell_item_id}_Parent",
                headers={
                    'referer': response.url,
                    'Content-type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'bearer null',
                    'Accept': '*/*',
                },
                callback=self.parse_cross_sell,
                meta={
                    'item': item,
                    'referer': response.url,
                    'cross_sell_items': cross_sell_items,
                }
            )
        else:
            # There is no "Others also bought" items for this page, just save main item
            yield item

    def parse_cross_sell(self, response):
        main_item = response.meta["item"]
        cross_sell_items = response.meta["cross_sell_items"]

        data = json.loads(response.text)
        current_cross_sell_item = {}
        current_cross_sell_item['title'] = data["_embedded"]["products"][0]["name"]
        current_cross_sell_item['url'] = data["_embedded"]["products"][0]["url"]
        current_cross_sell_item['description'] = data["_embedded"]["products"][0]["description"]

        main_item['cross_sell'].append(current_cross_sell_item)
        if cross_sell_items:
            cross_sell_item_id = cross_sell_items.pop(0)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                f"https://www.duif.nl/api/v2/catalog/product?itemcode={cross_sell_item_id}_Parent",
                headers={
                    'referer': response.meta['referer'],
                    'Content-type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'bearer null',
                    'Accept': '*/*',
                },
                callback=self.parse_cross_sell,
                meta={
                    'item': main_item,
                    'referer': response.meta['referer'],
                    'cross_sell_items': cross_sell_items,
                }
            )
        else:
            # no more cross sell items to process, save output
            yield main_item
```

Comment: Pipped me to the post! Saw there was an API endpoint and the ids were within the script.

Comment: hey @gangabass, can you pls go a little bit more in detail for me? im a beginner and i never touched json and i dont know where to start ._.

Comment: @gangabass, wow man, thanks for your edit! today i am going to learn json and try to understand your code :) i will edit my question and post my actual code, is it possible, to mix your solution with mine?

Comment: Sorry but I don't think so.

Comment: but i can add in ```def parse``` my other items which are required like delivery_status right? thanks at all kind sir!:)